# after execv, the contents in pipe buffer disappear

Tags: linux, pipe, execv

There are two process, parent process and child process
There are some data in parent process stdin. The content is:

```
the 1 line
the 2 line
the 3 line
the 4 line
```

The parent process code:

```
//parent
fgets(buffer, 1000, stdin);
printf("I have data:%s", buffer);   //print "I have data:the 1 line" 
if(!fork())
{
    fgets(buffer, 1000, stdin);
    printf("I have data:%s", buffer);   //print "I have data:the 2 line"
    execv("child", NULL);          
}
else
{
    exit(0);
}
```

The child process code:

```
//child
main()
{
    fgets(buffer, 1000, stdin);  //blocked if parent stdin content size<4096
    printf("I have no data:%s", buffer);  
}
```

why?
Is it possible for child process to read the third line in the stdin?

Answer (score 1):

`fgets` is a stdio function, so it uses the stdio buffer, which lives in the process's address space. When you exec, that buffer disappears with the rest of the original program, and the exec'ed program allocates its own stdio buffer.

If your file is seekable, then `fseek` to position 0 relative to `SEEK_CUR` before the exec might help (it can reposition the underlying fd to the correct point to continue reading from where stdio left off).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in my code, the source of parent process' stdin is a pipe which is not seekable. Is another way?

Comment: in a pipe, the only way to have the data remain for the child process is for the parent not to read it. That means it must do unbuffered, single-character reads so it can stop right on the `'\n'`. Try `setvbuf(stdin, 0, _IONBF, 0)` and see if that helps.

Comment: but if the content size of parent process stdin is large than 4K, child can read data. Why?

Comment: That's the size of the stdio buffer. Everything between the end of line 2 and the start of the second 4K-block is being lost.